# On click of icon changing to different icon only in mobile and tablet. But simulator its working good

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On click of the icon the icon is getting changed to other icon.
but in simulator it is working good like on clicking on that icon it change to fill color of that icon. 
what actually happening is on click of that it is changing to complete different icon.

Its happening in only mobile and tablet but that issue is not replicating in simulator of mobile and tablet in the browser.

Since i am not able to replicating the issue i am finding difficult to fix this issue
Please suggest some solution

[image]

[image]

like above it should come but its coming as complete different image please suggest some solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: @manoji stack for that you need to update with your code